# How to solve invalid parameter error using Codeigniter and Pesapal

Tags: codeigniter

Am trying to test my payment module using codeigniter and pesapal but I keep getting this error "Problem: parameter_rejected | Advice: invalid_value_for_amount> oauth_parameters_rejected | Ksh.4%2C999".

Where Ksh. 4%2C999 is the bill ksh. 4999. I have used the right Pesapal keys so I don't know what am doing wrong.

Comment: No code = no help, that's how SO works

Comment: I added this line    $amount = number_format((double)$amount, 2);
but i still get this error now: Problem: parameter_rejected | Advice: invalid_value_for_amount> oauth_parameters_rejected | 0.00

Answer (score 5):

**Problem**

Your amount has a thousand separator ... something like this Ksh.4,999 instead of passing a value that's an integer like 4999.

Either you are passing in the amount with the comma (which you can fix by removing the comma in your logic) or the `number_format()` method is adding the thousand separator (explanation given below in solution).

**Solution**

According to [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/number_format) `number_format()` does something like this (basic case only)...

```
// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235
```

Note how it's added a `,` as the thousand separator. This is what is being converted(encoded) to `%2C`. Pesapal doesn't understand numbers with the `,` which is what you are passing to them. ... to stop the function from using the thousands operator do something like this ...

```
// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

3rd parameter specifies the decimal separator (which is `.`) and the 4th specifies the thousand separator (which is an empty string).

But as @BabyAzerty has said, without code there's nothing much that we can work with to assist you. I'll amend the answer the more context you give to your problem but the above is pretty much what I've seen wrong with your implementation elaborated in the question and comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $amount1 = (integer)$data->amount;
        $amount = number_format($amount1, 2, '.', '');//format amount to 2 decimal places
        $desc = $data->phone_type;
        $type = "MERCHANT"; //default value = MERCHANT
        $reference = $data->reference;//unique order id of the transaction, generated by merchant
        $first_name = $data->name1;
        $last_name = $data->name2;
        $email = $data->email;
        $phonenumber = $data->mobile;//ONE of email or phonenumber is required
```

Comment: I have the issue, i did what @kingori maina suggested but getting Problem: parameter_rejected | Advice: invalid_value_amount_exceeds_limit> oauth_parameters_rejected | 84999.00

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your account on Pesapal has a limit on the amount it can transact. By default the amount is usually set to USD 10 or the equivalent of it in local currency.

You need to contact the team at support.pesapal.com to complete your sign-up by submitting contract and documents for your business in order to have the account activate for full transactions.